# cv2.imwrite returning false instead of saving image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am working on a code to save an image. Instead of saving image cv2.imwrite function is returning false. I have reproduced the problem in the below code:

```
Uni_ID = 123
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rett, img = cam.read()

now = datetime.now()
dtString =  now.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
timeString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
path = 'IMG'
name = path + '/' + dtString
#     print(name)
if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.makedirs(name)
imgName = name + '/'+ str(Uni_ID) + '_' + timeString + '.jpg'
print(imgName)
cv2.imwrite(imgName, img)
```

Instead of saving image, the cv2.imwrite function on the last line is returning false. The output of the code is :

```
IMG/03-09-2020/123_17:59:58.jpg
False
```

Comment: I guess you are using windows, that's why you get the problem since filenames with ':' are not considered. Instead you can use `/` or `-`, just change the `now.strftime('%H-%M-%S')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `:` in file name.

```
>>> cv2.imwrite(r'123_17:59:58.jpg', np.array(i))
False
>>> cv2.imwrite(r'123_17_59_58.jpg', np.array(i))
True
```

If you're not sure whether a filename would be valid or not - try opening it first.

```
>>> f = open(r'123_17:59:58.jpg', 'wt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '123_17:59:58.jpg'

>>> f = open(r'123_17_59_58.jpg', 'wt')
>>>
```

Comment: Nope, `cv2.imwrite(r'123_17:59:58.jpg', np.array(i))` is a perfectly valid command

Comment: Not in windows.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that (I'm on Linux, it worked fine for me). But I think the true issue here are the slashes in the name

Comment: I agree on that. TBH I think ```cv2``` need to raise error instead of returning ```False```. That's not pythonic -

Comment: Thank You, because of ":" the function was not able to save the image.

Comment: Agree that cv2 should throw more descriptive error. This same behavior in my case was caused by something totally different - the file name being too long.

Comment: @rajan Truely, there's related issue on cv2 repo but you can see them having 0 interest, few even saying 'why even wrap in `try-except`' - thanks to that we now have to wrap it with `try-open-except`..